# How get only a specific part of a string using a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

In an input field I have the value `A=123` and I need the JavaScript code to get only the `123` part.

This is what I tried so far:

```js
function formAnswer() {
    var input = document.getElementById('given').value;
    var match = input.match(/A=.*/);
    document.getElementById('result').value = match;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="given" placeholder="Given" value="A=123"/>
<input type="text" id="result" placeholder="Result"/>
<input type="button" value="Click!" onClick="formAnswer();"/>
```

But this still gets the value `A=123`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just an other note: you have no textarea, you only have text inputs.

Comment: If there can be digits only and that is the only allowed text you could use anchors to assert the start and the end of the string and capture in a group 1+ digits `^A=(\d+)$` See https://regex101.com/r/6FuzJR/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parenthesis in your regular expression to catch what's after `A=`. The caught value will be available with `match[1]` (`match[0]` will be the entire expression).

```js
function formAnswer() {
  let input = document.getElementById('given').value;
    match = input.match(/A=(.*)/);
    
  document.getElementById('result').value = match[1];
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="given" placeholder="Given"/>
<input type="text" id="result" placeholder="Result"/>
<input type="button" onClick="formAnswer();"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex: `(?<=A=).*`

It simply searches for a string which is preceded by "A="

```js
function formAnswer() {
  var input = document.getElementById('given').value;
  var match = input.match(/(?<=A=).*/);
  document.getElementById('result').value = match;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="given" placeholder="Given" value="A=123" />
<input type="text" id="result" placeholder="Result" />
<input type="button" onClick="formAnswer();" value="Check" />
```

Comment: Hi @JennyO'Reilly, it seems my eyes aren't working. It would be helpful if you will give some more info. (like, error message, input, etc)

Comment: Error is  due to compatibility of browser as lookbacks are not implemented in all the browsers

Comment: Sorry. I deleted the original comment. The error I get in Firefox 66.0.5 (Win64) is this one: `SyntaxError: invalid regexp group`. As Code Maniac pointed out, regex lookbacks in JavaScript are not supported by most browsers, as you can see here: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-RegExp_Lookbehind_Assertions